# Why am I getting a NullReferenceException with HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I have a VB.NET program, and I'm trying to read text from a webpage with HtmlAgilityPack. When I get to the line where I select the items on the page, I get the exception.

```
For Each div As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In page.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id ='clientname' and @id='clientkey']")
        MsgBox(div)
Next
```

Yes, the URL is valid. Here's the code that goes right before the for loop. uri is my URL variable

```
Dim web = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb()
Dim page = web.Load(uri)
```

Also, how do I put the content from "clientname" into a variable called ClientName, and the same with clientkey?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to use "or" instead of "and" in the selectnodes call?